# Problema envolvendo laços de repetição, fácil para quem já tem experiência com Python (O que não é o meu caso)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Eu preciso escrever um código para monitorar se um vulcão irá entrar em erupção ou não a cada valor inserido. A primeira linha da entrada consiste em "L", um inteiro correspondente ao
limite de pressão para erupção e as próximas linhas contêm inteiros "I" denotando as medições da pressão interna do vulcão, até que a entrada termine com 0 (zero). O código deve imprimir “ALARME”, assim que ocorrer "I > L", e "OK", caso não haja medições acima de "L". Ele deve imprimir só uma das frases por vez.

Isso foi o que eu fiz até agora, mas sem obter êxito:

```
L = int(input())
I = int(input())

while I != 0:
 I = int(input())
 if (I > L):
   break
 print("ALARME")
  
print("OK")
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá! Uma forma interessante de começarmos nossos códigos, é com uma reflexão de como eles deveriam funcionar através de um algoritmo, ou uma receita de bolo.

Sendo assim, se eu entendi sua necessidade, teremos:

```
Recebe o valor do Limite de Pressão

Recebe o primeiro valor da pressão medida do vulcão
    
Enquanto o valor de pressão for menor que o estipulado, continuar a medição
    
Se o valor for maior, emite um alarme e interrompe a medição
```

Eu entendi que você rodou bem todas as etapas anteriores, precisando apenas um ajuste no laço de repetição. Vamos lá, vou colocar o código abaixo e algumas dicas em cada etapa.

```
#Programa de Medição Contínua de Pressão em Python Utilizando Laços de Repetição

L = int(input("Digite o Limite de Pressão do Vulcão: ")) #Recomendo sempre digitar um texto para identificar o input na hora de rodar

while True: #a variável I que estava aqui antes faz com que o while nem inicie, pois I já teria um valor diferente de 0. O mais adequado aqui é "while True" pois você não sabe quantas repetições serão executadas e o break servirá para interromper o laço.
 I = int(input("Digite a nova medição de pressão do vulcão: ")) #Você pode manter apenas aqui o input do I, já que estará condicionado ao laço
 if (I > L):
     print("ALARME - MEDIÇÃO ACIMA DO NORMAL")     #movi o print para cá, visto que o código somente será executado se (por isso o IF) a pressão for maior que o estipulado (I>L)
     break
 else:
     print("OK") #o correto é adicionar um else, que é um "se não". Ou seja, se não estiver acima do valor que é o que o "If (I > L)" significa que está abaixo, então OK.
```

Espero ter ajudado. Continue praticando, talvez como desafio tente fazer um outro laço, perguntando se mesmo após o alerta, ainda quer continuar medindo ou não.